# SQL Server 2012 mirror in azure VM - on second failover app loses connectivity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

We've got a mirrored SQL server 2012 database setup on Azure VM's - two servers plus a witness, all using client certificates, with SQL logins with the same SID set.

When testing our app from a different VM, everything works as expected when we manually failover the database, there's a one second wait and then it continues to operate quite happily.

If we then do another manual failover, ie moving the principal back to the original server, the app errors and throws a 'no such host in known' error. Recycling the app pool fixes the issue, but this clearly isn't workable in production when one of the servers is updated followed by the other at some later point (both are in an availability set).

The host not known error is somewhat baffling as it was communicating with it happily before the initial failover, and will again after the app pool recycle.

Here's the connection string as it is right now, after a lot of faffing around:

> "Data Source=server1,1433;Failover Partner=server2,1433;Initial
>   Catalog=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=user;
>   Password=password; Network=dbmssocn;Connect Timeout=60; async = true;"
>   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

The app is running on .net 4.5.2, so should be up to date with hotfixes, and we're out of ideas after much Googling with Bing.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved a problem that I had that looks very similar to your problem. I'd get the host not known error whenever the database switched from the first one listed in the web.config file to the failover one.  It was fine switching from the failover to the primary.

The problem that I had was that I set up the database mirroring using server names but my web server did not know the database servers by name.  Once I fixed this, I was able to get the failover working smoothly both ways.

This is what I think was happening:

- I set up the mirroring using the names `SQL1` and `SQL2` as the principal and mirror servers
- I have their ip addresses in my connection string: `10.1.1.5` and `10.1.1.6`
- The application tries to get to the first server `10.1.1.5` and succeeds and is then told that the mirror server is `SQL2`
- `SQL1` goes down and the database is successfully switched to the mirror server.
- The web application attempts to connect, fails and determines that it should try the second server.
- It tries to connect to `SQL2`, which it doesn't know, and fails with the message that the host is unknown.

This answer would only apply to your situation if you actually put ip addresses in your web.config and that `server1,1433` and `server2,1433` were actually masking place-holders for the ip addresses that you actually used.

I haven't really solved the naming issue though.  I just added the two database server names to the HOSTS file which isn't an acceptable situation but does prove my theory on what my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I am researching a setup just like you have and upon reading this and the response by Steve Kaye, I'm wondering if you have SQL browser running. Take a look at this article for how SQL browser comes into play:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/15/running-a-database-mirror-setup-with-the-sqlbrowser-service-off-may-produce-unexpected-results.aspx